# Alternative popup notifications on Ubuntu 20.04 - Mate?

Tags: 20.04, mate, notification

Since the upgrade to 20.04, I have switched to Mate due to it being the most similar interface Gnome (flashback) which is what I used on 18.04 and no longer works correctly.

I am trying to work out a way of changing the notifications for things such as emails, messages on skype, discord and other social media stuff as well as music tracks playing.

The area I’ve looked is in the Mate Control Centre and “Popup Notifications”. I have it at the top right which is the default, but there are a couple of things I can’t find a way to change. The program seems very restricted regarding options. It shows up to 5 notifications at once, one under another which I consider to be excessive. On 18.04 and gnome flashback, it showed one notification and wouldn’t show another if it was still there which kept things minimal.

[Mate Control Center "Popup Notifications" Preview test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4P35d.png)

The other problem is that I can’t find a way to keep the notifications brief such as only showing a certain number of characters. I’m used to it limiting the length and ending the words with several dots so that the popup sign never exceeded a certain size and was consistent. Now it at times is huge.

This is an example below of an overly long track name on Spotify that is hardly just a notification on the top right any more. I understand that is the track name, but why can't the notifications all be the same size?

[Excessively long "notification" for a music track that is playing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uhrk.png)

The same happens if a link or long message is shared via chat and sometimes, one message can take up nearly 25% of my desktop space. All I need is a brief notification, not seeing the entire message at once as well as sometimes multiple at once. It also doesn’t pop up every time so it seems somewhat unreliable.

Are there any add-ons I can install that are more reminiscent of the old Gnome (flashback) that are specifically for notifications or is there something more obvious in the preferences I’m missing?

Thanks.